# How to use perspective in GLM?

Tags: opengl, transform, glm-math

I'm trying to learn to use OpenGL. I'm having problems using glm::perspective. whenever I put this into the transform matrix, nothing displays in the window. What am I doing wrong?

shader code:

```
//vertex shader
#version 450 core
layout (location = 0)
in vec3 position;
uniform mat4 transform;
void main(){
gl_Position =transform*vec4(position.xyz, 1.0);
}
```

code that determines what value uniform variable (transform) is equal to:

```
glm::mat4 transform;
transform = glm::perspective(45.0f, (float)900/(float)600, 0.1f, 100.0f);
transform = glm::translate(transform, glm::vec3(cos(time)/2, sin(time)/2,0.0f));
transform = glm::rotate(transform(GLfloat)time, glm::vec3(sin(time), cos(time*2), 0.0f));`
```

It works fine until I put the glm::perspective part in there. then it doesn't display at all in the window.

Comment: What are the positions you are trying to render? Are you sure that they *should* be visible, given your perspective matrix?

Comment: Draw an unit cube stationed at origin as reference, as a good practice. Get it to render in perspective then others will be easier.

Answer (score 0):

probably too late but the first argument for glm::perspective is a radian. I assume you meant to input 45 degree